# Best way to parse a stringstream

Tags: c++

I currently have a `std::stringstream` that contains all the data from a given file. This file contains some text as well as binary data.

In the beginning there is a string name, so I get it this way:

```
std::string name;
std::getline(stream, name, '\0');
```

Later on, I need to retrieve the `contentLength`. Part where I'm failing:

```
int32_t contentLength;
stream >> contentLength;
```

I learned that this won't work, since the `stream` `>>` operator will try to **convert** instead of **casting** my 4 bytes with the literal value of the `length`.

I have seen some low level (`c`) implementation of how to do that. But I would like you guys to advise me of a more reliable way of doing it.

Comment: `stream.read((char*)&contentLength, sizeof(contentLength));`

Comment: What has the name to do with your particular question?

Comment: Just an example of how I started...

Comment: what do you mean by "file contains some text as well as binary data"? The content length is represented in binary format instead of text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `read` function to read binary data.

```
stream.read((char*)&contentLength, sizeof(contentLength));
```

You just need to be careful if you share this file between computers with different [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), in which case the bytes might need to be reversed.

Comment: And how do I get the position of the cursor after using `.read()`?

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino: It's `sizeof(contentLength)` bytes past what it was before the call.

Comment: The same way as you do it before using `read` - `stream.tellg()`